# How to send current URL in JavaScript to a second PHP page?

Tags: javascript

I want to sent current URL from Page1 to a php page called upload_picture.php.

I look at another question and this is an option:

On Page1

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/uas_tools/visualization_generator/V2/Resources/PHP/upload_picture.php',
    data: 'url=' + window.location.toString()
});
```

If using this option, on upload_picture.php, how to get the URL sent from Page1?

Comment: Did you mean to navigate to the html with the data? or just do an ajax to an HTML page?

Comment: `window.location.replace(...)`

Comment: Can php pages have the extension `.html`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox You can configure the extensions how you want. For security reasons it's even better to completely remove them.

Comment: @AdarshMohan, I mean just do an ajax to an HTML page

Comment: What is your exact question. It's unclear for me. Do you want to send an URL and receive a reponse (what type of response)? Or do you want to send an image and receive an URL?

Comment: @ThomasSablik I want to sent current URL from Page1 to a different html page called upload_picture.html.

Comment: HTML doesn't read post data. You need a scripting language to preprocess the page to get the data. something like a `php`. or if you are navigating to the page, you can use `location.search` to get the query data

Comment: Yes, that's what your code is actually doing. What is your question?

Comment: @ThomasSablik how to get the URL sent from Page1?

Comment: if you mean to navigate to next url use `location.href = 'new url`

Comment: To make it clear before I write my answer. Do you want to send an URL and receive an URL?

Comment: @ThomasSablik, yes, I do. If it cannot be done to a HTML page, I will send it to a PHP page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to call the ajax will be as this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/uas_tools/visualization_generator/V2/Resources/PHP/upload_picture.php',
    data: { url: location.href },
    success: function(response) {
        // your success callback
    },
    error: function () {
        // your error callback
    }
});
```

And on the php page you can retrieve the data as

```
<?php

$page_url = $_POST['url'];
```

Comment: I am getting ```Undefined index: url in /var/www/html/uas_tools/visualization_generator/V2/Resources/PHP/upload_picture.php on line 2```

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST)` to see what you have in the post data